# Default or fallback container (docker) in traefik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm using traefik and docker to run multiple services on my server. How can I specify a default or fallback container, if there is no matching container for a (sub-)domain? For example, I'm using example.com for my website and cloud.example.com for my nextcloud. But when someone is using www.example.com or wiki.example (or one of the other possible subdomains) it shoud redirect to my website and not showing a 404 error page.

Each container has the following labels:

```
  - traefik.port=<port>
  - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:<sub-1>.example.com,<sub-2>.example.com
  - traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https
```

The traefik configuration is here (I'm using the `traefik:1.6-alpine` image):

```
# General
logLevel = "INFO"

# EntryPoints
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"

    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"

  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"

    [entryPoints.https.tls]

# Let's Encrypt
[acme]
  entryPoint = "https"
  email = "info@example.com"
  storage = "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
  onHostRule = true
  [acme.httpChallenge]
    entryPoint = "http"
  [[acme.domains]]
    main = "example.com"

# Docker
[docker]
  domain = "localhost"
  watch = true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want *all* traffic but a few subdomains to go to your web container:

replace: `traefik.frontend.rule=Host:<sub-1>.example.com,<sub-2>.example.com`

with: `traefik.frontend.rule=HostRegexp:{subdomain:[a-z0-9]+}.example.com`, and add a priority label of 10: `traefik.frontend.priority=10`.

Then set a higher priority on any other services that you want to match before falling back to your website.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine. Do you know, how to get certificates for this new subdomains?

Comment: You can either add more domains to your `acme.domains` list, or you can look at requesting a wildcard certificate. Note that requesting a wildcard certificate requires the DNS challenge.